# Moment inequality for average of centered iid random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, average

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$ and such that $|X_1| \leq m < \infty$ almost surely, and let
$$
\bar X_N = \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N X_i
$$
be the arithmetic mean. Given a positive integer $p$, I believe that it should hold for the $2p$-th moment $M_{2p} = \mathbb{E}[\bar X_N^{2p}]$ an estimate of the form
$$
M_{2p} \leq C_p\frac1{N^{p}},
$$
under suitable integrability conditions on the random variables, and where $C_p$ is a constant depending only on $p$. Is there any simple result that guarantees this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p\ge 1$,
$$
\mathsf{E}|\bar{X}_n|^{2p}\le \frac{C_{p}}{n^{p}}\times \mathsf{E}|X_1|^{2p},
$$
where $C_p$ is a constant depending only on $p$. (See, e.g., Section III.5 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zSDqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA336&dq#v=onepage&q=(Dharmadhikari%20and%20Jogdeo%20%5B201%5D)&f=false))